# Google Earth - How can I insert multiples of the same placemark model at different lat/lon coordinates?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I have a complex wind turbine model that I'm inserting at 130 different locations.  The wind turbine model is actually 8 sub-models (a-h) that simulate blade rotation. I'm using setVisibility in a while-loop with a timeout delay to have one sub-model visble at a time; works great.

Here's my problem:  When I insert (using placemark) my 8 sub-models at the 130 locations, I have to insert my while-loop into a huge for-loop to address each of the 1040 models to turn them on and off individually, because they behave as individual entities.  This works, but results in very choppy behavior; too much data. Clunky.  There has to be a better way.

What I want to learn: Can I insert the 8 sub-models in 130 locations, and have all 130 "a" models turn on with one setVisibility(true) command?  That way, my while loop would work and I could get rid of the for loop.

I can post my code, but there's a lot of other peripheral crap in there and my programming skills are embarrassing...

Comment: How on `Earth` do you expect to do *that*? :)

Comment: The irony...  In all seriousness, I'm hoping that I could simplify my for-loop if setVisibility could support wild cards, or  maybe if the same model could be dropped in many locations, and setVisibility would control all of the models, no matter where they were or how many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
use multiGeometry.getGeometries().appendChild(model);
```

attributes can be changed with one command using a multiGeometry.  Don't forget to make your variable global if you're working outside of a function.